# Named router views

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I'm building a Nuxt app with a layout that consists of 3/4 main content and 1/4 sidebar navigation that uses tabs that expand based on the current route.

My aim is to essentially have two router-views — one on the main page and one in each tab.

With the Vue Router I guess this would be possible to achieve via named views  e.g.

```
<router-view name="rightSidebar"></router-view>
```

But obviously with Nuxt the idea is that the routing is taken care of behind the scenes...so it isn't possible to configure.

But none the less is it possible to use `<NuxtPage />` in this way?

Answer (score 1):

### In Nuxt3

**For *named router views*...**

The `<NuxtPage>` component has `name` prop; see [Nuxt docs - NuxtPage](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page). Presumably this could be useful if you have many router views.

```
<NuxtPage :name="myViewName" />
```

---

**For *named routes*, use special meta...**

In page meta, there are special reserved properties that invoke high-level adaptions. See [Nuxt docs - Pages Special Metadata](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#special-metadata).

**Set a `name` property in page meta:**

**pages/mypage.vue**

```
definePageMeta({
    name: 'myCustomRouteName' // Gets passed to route object
    title: 'My Custom Page Title',
    
    // Custom meta like...
    myBreadcrumbTitle: 'Some Text Here' 
})
```

**The route object will become like this:**

```
{
    "name": "myCustomRouteName",
    "path": "mypage",
    "meta": {
      "title": "My Custom Page Title",
      "myBreadcrumbTitle": "Some Text Here"
    },
    "alias": []
}
```

**And you can do stuff like:**

Render `<NuxtLink>`'s by name...

```
<NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'myCustomRouteName'}">
    My link text
</NuxtLink>
```

... call the route programmatically...

```
function navigate(){
    return navigateTo({
        name: 'myCustomRouteName'
    })
}
```

or build a breadcrumb component, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I could find only one way to use [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html) with the [NuxtPage](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page) component in Nuxt 3. You need to set up [custom routes](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing).

Add a file called `app/router.options.ts` in your project. (I don't know why it needs to be in a folder called `app`, other than that the docs say so.) Inside of that file, you can tweak the existing routes, and replace `component: PageComponent` with `components: {default: PageComponent, foo: SomeComponent, bar: AnotherComponent}`.

Examples below. Ask in the comments if you need more examples.

### Example 1: Add a toolbar to a specific route:

```
import { RouterConfig } from "@nuxt/schema";

export default <RouterConfig>{
  routes: (routes) => {
    return routes
      .map((route) => {
        const name = String(route.name);

        if (name.startsWith("test-withToolbar")) {
          return {
            ...route,
            component: undefined,
            components: {
              default: route.component, // This is a component from the `pages` folder. Use it with `NuxtPage`.
              toolbar: () => import("~/toolbars/MyToolbar.vue"), // Use this with `NuxtPage(name="toolbar")`.
            },
          };
        }

        return route;
      });
  },
};
```

Then in `app.vue` (or in a layout file if you want to use layouts), you could have this template (I'm using Pug syntax instead of HTML for brevity):

```
div
  NuxtPage(name="toolbar")
  NuxtPage
```

### Example 2: Add toolbars and footers automatically by path

Maybe we want to have a `toolbars` folder that behaves similarly to the `pages` folder. Then we could do something like this in `app/router.options.ts`:

```
import type { RouterConfig } from "@nuxt/schema";
import { readdirSync } from "fs";
import type { Component } from "@vue/runtime-core";

export default <RouterConfig>{
  routes: (routes) => {
    const toolbarNames = readdirSync("./toolbars").map((name) =>
      name.replace(/\.vue$/, "")
    );

    return routes.map((route) => {
      const name = String(route.name);

      if (!route.component) {
        return route;
      }

      const components: Record<string, Component> = {
        default: route.component,
      };

      if (toolbarNames.includes(name)) {
        components.toolbar = () => import(`~/toolbars/${name}.vue`);
      }

      return {
        ...route,
        component: undefined,
        components,
      };
    });
  },
};
```

This allows you to have a different toolbar on each page, while using the same layout, e.g.:

```
div
  NuxtPage(name="toolbar")
  NuxtPage
```

### Example 3: Specify route components using page metadata

I had the idea of using the [`definePageMeta` macro](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-page-meta) to add metadata to the components in the `pages` folder, and then use that in `app/router.options.ts` to add other components. However, it seems that `definePageMeta` is ignored or overwritten when `app/router.options.ts` is present. See https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/19700 . If I figure out a way to do this, I will update this answer.

Comment: This worked when I put NuxtPage in my layout file. Is it possible to put NuxtPage inside another page?

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt.js does not support the `router-view`. However, you can use the `NuxtPage` inbuilt component. Just remember that it only works after the pages you are trying to nest have been added in the `pages` directory.

Here is a [link](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page) to an overview of it from the Nuxt docs.

Comment: I'm aware that router-view isn't supported by Nuxt so I guess my question was more about how to use named routes with NuxtPage — the documentation doesn't specify much about this :(